# Maya python CHANGE UVTILE with place2dTexture

Tags: python, maya

In python I want to select one object and change repeatUV .

The code work for all objects and not for one specific object

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import pymel.core as pmc

def UVTILECHANGE():

    selected = cmds.ls(sl=True)

    textField_obj_name = cmds.textField( 'textField_action_name',query=True,text=True )

    textField_obj = cmds.textField( 'textField_action',query=True,text=True )
    #print textField_obj
    textField_obj2 = cmds.textField( 'textField_action2',query=True,text=True )

    if  textField_obj_name==selected[0]:  

        array = cmds.ls(type="place2dTexture")
        #SELECT ALL PLACE2DTECTURE
        #I WANT JUST FOR selected[0]
        #print len(array)
        i=0
        while (i <= len(array)):
            print 
            cmds.setAttr(str(array[i])+ ".repeatU", float(textField_obj))

            cmds.setAttr(str(array[i])+ ".repeatV", float(textField_obj2))
            i=i+1

def MakeWindow():

    if (pmc.window('flattenVertwindow', exists=True)):
        pmc.deleteUI('flattenVertwindow')

    pmc.window('flattenVertwindow', title="TEST",widthHeight=(200,100))
    pmc.columnLayout(adjustableColumn=True)
    #pmc.text(label='select axis')
    cmds.text("Choisir nom de l'objet")
    cmds.separator(h=10)
    textField00 = cmds.textField( 'textField_action_name' )
    cmds.separator(h=10)
    cmds.text("Taille des Tiles")
    cmds.separator(h=10)
    textField01 = cmds.textField( 'textField_action' )
    textField02 = cmds.textField( 'textField_action2' )
    red= pmc.button(label='Change UV TILE ', command= 'UVTILECHANGE()')

    pmc.showWindow('flattenVertwindow')


MakeWindow()
```

Comment: For *which* object does it not work? What is different from this object to all the other objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure what doesn't work, Ive improved your code with comments.
I hope it will help, it works here :

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import pymel.core as pmc

# if you dont know classes, you can create a dict to store all main controls
UI_DIC = {}

# for function used in ui, you need *args because maya will try to parse a default True
# argument as last argument
def picker(*args):
    sel = cmds.ls(sl=True)[0]
    cmds.textField(UI_DIC['textField00'], edit=True, text=sel )

# use lower case for functions, you can use camel casing like maya : uvTilesChange
# but keep the first letter lower case as uppercase for the first is used for Class
def uv_tile_change(*args):

    # we parse fields with the value captured in the dictionnary
    textField_obj_name = cmds.textField(UI_DIC['textField00'], query=True, text=True )
    textField_obj = cmds.textField(UI_DIC['textField01'], query=True, text=True )
    textField_obj2 = cmds.textField(UI_DIC['textField02'], query=True, text=True )

    # if there is nothing in the ui, dont execute anything
    if not textField_obj_name:
        return

    # we are using few funcitons to find the place2dTexture of an object
    shape_mesh = cmds.ls(textField_obj_name, dag=True, type='shape', ni=True)
    if not shape_mesh:
        # if the object doesnt exists, stop here
        return
    # we look for the shading engine of the object
    hist = cmds.listHistory(shape_mesh, future=True)
    sgs = cmds.ls(hist, type="shadingEngine")
    # from the sgs, we look for the place2dTexture
    place2dTextures = [i for i in cmds.listHistory(sgs) if cmds.ls(i, type='place2dTexture')]
    # instead of a while, just use a python for loop
    for p2t in place2dTextures:
        cmds.setAttr(p2t + ".repeatU", float(textField_obj))
        cmds.setAttr(p2t + ".repeatV", float(textField_obj2))

def make_window():

    width = 180
    height = 150

    if (pmc.window('flattenVertwindow', exists=True)):
        pmc.deleteUI('flattenVertwindow')

    # sizeable works for me
    pmc.window('flattenVertwindow', title="TEST",widthHeight=(width,height), sizeable=False)
    main_layout = pmc.columnLayout(adjustableColumn=True)
    # use the flag parent, it is more clear
    pmc.text("Choisir nom de l'objet", parent=main_layout)
    # choose either cmds or pymel, do not use both
    pmc.separator(h=10, parent=main_layout)

    # here is an example on how parent flag is useful
    # we create a sub layout and parent it to the main one
    # we parent all the controls to the sub layout
    picker_layout = pmc.rowLayout(nc=3, parent=main_layout, width=width, ad1=True)
    # we capture the name of the control on creation inside the dict
    UI_DIC['textField00'] = pmc.textField(parent=picker_layout, w=width)
    # take the habit to not put string in the command flag
    pmc.button(label='<', command= picker, parent=picker_layout)

    pmc.separator(h=10, parent=main_layout)
    pmc.text("Taille des Tiles", parent=main_layout)
    pmc.separator(h=10)
    UI_DIC['textField01'] = pmc.textField(parent=main_layout)
    UI_DIC['textField02'] = pmc.textField(parent=main_layout)
    red= pmc.button(label='Change UV TILE ', command= uv_tile_change, parent=main_layout)

    pmc.showWindow('flattenVertwindow')


make_window()
```